# What's event when keyboard appear to input text in WebBrowser control Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, keyboard-events

I want to paste something to textbox in WebBrowser when keyboard appear. I try this:

```
webBrowser.Input += ((o,e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input started");
});
```

but nothing happen when virtual keyboard appear (same result with InputStart and InputUpdate event). Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

WP8's WebBrowser has a very poor interface compared to W8 and WPF. I'm not sure either support Input/InputStart/InputUpdate (definitely not supported in WP8), so you're out of luck with those callbacks.

The only real way you can operate on the WebBrowser content is using `InvokeScript`.

If you can't modify the site Html (you're providing an Url link not an HtmlString to the WebBrowser), then the route would be to use InvokeScript on a JavaScript function that will attach a listener event to the textbox, with your JavaScript function hard-coding the value you want to paste. There may be issues with getting the keyboard to open due to focus, but I believe this is the only way you will be able to manage to paste something like you've described.